# Python csv module skips tab delimiters when writing to file

Tags: python, csv

I have an issue with a csv module for Python 3.6. I need to write some data to csv file in 4 columns with tab as a delimiter. I set it explicitly:

```
outputFile = open('test_tasks.csv', 'w', newline='')
outputWriter = csv.writer(outputFile, delimiter='\t')

for item in range(len(data)):
    outputWriter.writerow(['created: ' + data[item]['created'], 'status: ' + data[item]['status'], 'coordinates: ' + data[item]['tasks'][0]['input_values']['coordinates'], 'id: ' + data[item]['tasks'][0]['id'], 'user_id ' + data[0]['user_id']])
```

But when I open resulting file in, for example, Windows Notepad, I see that from time to time there is just one space instead of tab between columns. Most commonly when preceding value is shorter (contains fewer symbols) than usual. Example:

```
created: 2017-01-19T04:39:41.012 status: EXPIRED coordinates: 56.91969408920,60.03087172680  id: ffbc4048-cc5a-4578-b0d9-0705a588b55d    user_id 165684b434e6390fb8da262978601397
created: 2017-02-24T16:08:10.280    status: EXPIRED coordinates: 55.915326,37.869891    id: 90437e00-d15c-4679-b7be-6d3660efdbce    user_id 165684b434e6390fb8da262978601397
created: 2016-12-09T14:16:43.240    status: ACCEPTED    coordinates: 55.683752,37.491063    id: 831c4cef-7eb1-4a3e-9a27-037d8c12ce28    user_id 165684b434e6390fb8da262978601397
created: 2017-01-08T10:06:30.454    status: ACCEPTED    coordinates: 59.958408,30.331696    id: e1b1f2c1-bcd7-4394-90cb-df54bfe082aa    user_id 165684b434e6390fb8da262978601397
created: 2017-02-12T13:20:27.100    status: ACCEPTED    coordinates: 55.762166,37.619099    id: bc648343-d71a-41af-8ae6-d6fa60946824    user_id 165684b434e6390fb8da262978601397
created: 2017-03-23T22:00:25.362    status: ACCEPTED    coordinates: 56.284944,43.929684    id: a9c94269-d128-428b-a62d-911be9693b5a    user_id 165684b434e6390fb8da262978601397
```

Am I missing something or is it some csv module bug? Is there any way to write csv file with tab delimiters properly using Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem here. Python outputs tab characters just fine. Tab characters are not *fixed with spacers*, they only move the cursor to the *next tab stop*. If that next tab stop is just one space away you get exactly your output.

Tab stops are usually set at *fixed width intervals*, every 4 or 8 spaces is common. A tab character can then move the cursor from anywhere between 1 and 7 spaces, depending on the current cursor position.

Try out the following code and open the resulting `tabs.txt` in your Notepad text editor:

```
with open('tabs.txt', 'w') as f:
    digits = '0123456789'
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print(digits[:i] + '\tNext column', file=f)
```

and you'll see something like this:

```
0   Next column
01  Next column
012 Next column
0123    Next column
01234   Next column
012345  Next column
0123456 Next column
01234567    Next column
012345678   Next column
0123456789  Next column
```

Those first 4 lines could have the *Next Column* text moved another 4 spaces if you have a tab-stop size of 8 instead of 4; Stack Overflow has configured tab-stops at every 4th column, hence the rendering here.

If you need to have a fixed-width output, *don't use tab characters*, or even the `csv` module. Use string formatting instead, with specified column widths:

```
with open('test_tasks.csv', 'w') as outputFile:
    for entry in data:
        outputWriter.write(
            f"created: {entry['created']:<23} "
            f"status: {entry[status]:<8} "
            f"coordinates: {entry['tasks'][0]['input_values']['coordinates']:<30} "
            f"id: {entry['tasks'][0]['id']:<36} "
            f"user_id {entry['user_id']}\n")
```

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you. So there is nothing wrong with my ouptut then, right?